# Simple sentence that I'm not sure is right

Tags: grammar

I just want to know if this sentence is right:

"It contributed to the decision of start respecting people"

If it's not. How can I fix it? I've no idea if I should use contributed for or start to instead.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: *It contributed to the decision* ***to*** *start respecting people.*

Comment: The OP has already re-posted their question [on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31676/contributed-to-contributed-for-or-start-to).  Since this copy of the question has answers, if the ELU mods feel they have any value, I think the right thing to do might be to migrate this question to ELL and ask an ELL moderator to merge the two.  I've left a flag to this effect; in the meantime, I voted to close to keep two copies of the question from being in play at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

"It contributed to the decision of starting to respect people" if the decision was made with respect to respecting people more.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

"It contributed to the decision to start respecting people."